# Handling doubles with large integer parts in C++

Tags: c++, types, double, rounding-error

I need to handle sub-metre coordinates in C++ which have large integer parts (e.g. 515876.12 // 5117789.22), but I'm having issues with rounding:

```
double inUTMX = 560351.12 is displayed as 560351
double inUTMY = 5113570.22 is displayed as 5.11357e+06
```

I can normalise the coordinates for processing if necessary (e.g. /1e5), but I need to read-in the sub-metre coordinates via command line in the first place.  Trouble is they always get rounded.

Is there a neat way to deal with doubles that have large integer values in C++?

(Tried it in Python it stores the entire precision fine as a float, just wondering where I'm going wrong.)

Any ideas / pointers much appreciated.

Comment: What specifically makes you think that “double inUTMX = 560351.12 is stored as 560351”?

Comment: That numbers look way to small that the integer part exceeds a double´s precision. Probably an output problem.

Comment: *is stored as* should be *is displayed as*.

Comment: Cout gives me the rounded value also processing results in stepped output values because all my calculations are rounded to integers.

Comment: There are a lot of formatting flags to help you there. setprecision, fixed and so on.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe - Thanks - setprecision sorted it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify how `double`s are streamed by using `std::setprecision`.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main () {
   double inUTMX = 560351.12;
   double inUTMY = 5113570.22;

   std::cout << std::setprecision(20) << inUTMX << std::endl;
   std::cout << std::setprecision(20) << inUTMY << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
560351.11999999999534
5113570.2199999997392
```